# Assembly cleaning up stack in CDECL causes crash

Tags: assembly, freepascal

```
Function CallFunc(Address: PtrUInt; Arg: Array of PtrUInt; isCDecl: Boolean = True): PtrUInt;
{$ASMMODE INTEL}
begin
  if (isCDecl) then
  asm
    mov ecx, 3  //loop 3 times.
    mov edx, Arg
    @@start:
      dec ecx
      push dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4] //push 3 pointers onto the stack.
    jnz @@start
    call [Address]

    //Do cleanup
    mov ecx, 3
    @@end:
      dec ecx
      pop dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4] //pop each pointer off the stack.
    jnz @@end

    mov @Result, eax
  end;
end;
```

However, I get a segfault when cleaning up. If I don't pop the arguments off the stack, it does not segfault.

Do I need to pop the arguments off the stack in this case or is it safe to leave it?

I tried to do "ret 12" but that fails as well.

Comment: But you lost me. This function is the caller. It "call [Address]" then it has to clean it up right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your edx contains garbage after returning from call [Address], so who knows what you are popping into.
2. You don't need to pop into any memory.  Just pop edx 3 times.

Comment: Ahh! Didn't notice that. Was busting my brain trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Ahaha. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to be of help, but please tell me, does this actually fix the problem?

Comment: You don't even need to `pop` 3 times, you can simply adjust the stack pointer (`add esp, 12`).